# postgres pg_restore

Tags: postgresql

Как при перемещении данных из одной базы в другую сделать так, чтоб данные, которые уже есть в базе - пропускались?

```
ssh -i /home/centos/.ssh/id_rsa centos@src_host "PGPASSWORD=123123 pg_dump -U user_1 -h src_host -p 5432 -d test-1 -Fc -t 1 -t 2 -t 3 > /tmp/users.sql"
scp -i /home/centos/.ssh/id_rsa centos@src_host:/tmp/users.sql  centos@dst_host:~/users.sql
ssh -i /home/centos/.ssh/id_rsa centos@dst_host "PGPASSWORD=123123 pg_restore -U user_2 -d test-2 -O -x -1 ~/users.sql"
```

Comment: А  что именно Вы сделали уже сами? С какой проблемой при реализации заливки столкнулись?

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: есть 3 машины.
на двух базы, с третьей работаю.
проблема в том, что данные либо перезаписываются (с ключом -c) либо отлетает ошибка на already exists таблички.
просто в таблицах сидят юзеры и нужно именно синхронизировать базы, а не делать замену.

Comment: @V.March отписал